# setContinuousRendering(false). No action animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I use the following methods when creating my Game class object:
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering (false);

But I have a problem: When I add a MoveToAction to an actor, render is called once, so that the animation is not visible completely.

With the rest of the actors there are no problems - for example, the animation of ScrollPane is working.

Comment: I decided this using getRawDeltaTime() instead of the getDeltaTime() in my Game class.

Comment: Discussion: https://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=27943